# ORACLE: Convert a string to number with a mask

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like convert a string to number with a mask in oracle​ but my problema is when I execute:

```
​SELECT TO_NUMBER('9.9' , '999G999G999G999G999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ') FROM dual;
```

the Result I get is : 99​

But this result is not ok. The correct result is 9.9 or Oracle should display some error
​
How can I do?

​
​
​Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware then when you fix this (see @Aleksej answer), the string '9.900' (for example) will throw an invalid number (because it fails your mask).  Not sure if that's your intention or not

Comment: @tbone  I'd like to convert a string to number, using the " , " for decimals and " . " for the thousands. I dont care what mask to use, my problem is that when I execute the sentences I think it should be wrong. The sentences: with string 9.9 y 9.99 Is my problem However with 999.9 Oracle display error. Can you help me please ?

Comment: If you want comma ',' for the decimal separator, then instead of 999.9 you should have the string 999,9

Answer (score 3):

The issue is **we** think of `G` as **thousands** separator. Oracle doesn't think of it that way; it is a separator that may appear anywhere in the integer part of a number. With your setting `.` as the "thousands" separator, Oracle will take your **input string** (in your case `9.9`) and disregard any occurrence of `.` when it reads it as a number. So your `9.9` really means 99 to Oracle.

The **real** question that remains is why does Oracle ignore your format model. That I don't know - it's probably Big Brother Oracle "guessing what you meant" even if it is not exactly what you said. It does the same in many other instances.

Note that

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('9.9.7.9' , '999G999G999G999G999G999G999D99',
                       'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ') FROM dual;
```

works perfectly fine and it produces the number 9979.

Comment: @BGF - Aleksej has already shown how to do this correctly. In `nls_numeric_characters` the decimal separator (`.` in your case) should be the first one, not the second one.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to convert a string to number, using the " , "  for decimals  and " . "  for the thousands.
I dont care what mask to use, my problem is that when I execute the sentences I think it should be wrong.
The sentences: with string 9.9 y 9.99 Is my problem 
However with 999.9 Oracle display error.

Comment: If you can help me to execute the sentence so that it works, when the string has decimal is by decimals and with point is for thousands

Comment: The question is :  I'd like to convert a string to number, using the " , " for decimals and " . " for the thousands. I dont care what mask to use, my problem is that when I execute the sentences I think it should be wrong. The sentences: with string 9.9 y 9.99 Is my problem However with 999.9 Oracle display error. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' '` which means that `','` is the separator for decimals and `'.'` is the group separator ( for thousands in your example), according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS.htm#REFRN10126).

Simply replacing  this with `'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' '` should work.

Comment: I am sure the OP knows that - and that is EXACTLY why he asked. The question is why Oracle doesn't throw an error with THAT query.

Comment: (Of course, I've been "sure" and "wrong" at the same time before. Perhaps the OP did not know about the correct order of D and G in `nls_numeric_characters`.)

Comment: I was just trying to get your point, and it's a good interpretation however, no matter if it suits the OP's real intention or not.

Comment: I use the commas for the decimals and the points for the thousands, replacing with 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' is no work

Comment: If you "use the commas for the decimals and the points for the thousands", what should '9.9' mean? Why should it be converted into 9.9?

Comment: @Aleksej The input can be 9.9 and should be error, like a execute 999.9 and display error

Comment: @BGF - I am still not sure what you are asking. Please confirm if this is correct: I **think** (now) that you want Oracle to throw an error when you give it the input string '9.9' and the format model '9G999' and you tell it that the "thousands" separator is the period `.` RIGHT? I agree with you; in my answer, I showed with an additional example that Oracle will "forgive you for providing the wrong mask/format model" and still accept the input, instead of throwing an error. Are you asking, how can you make Oracle throw an error in that case?

Comment: @mathguy I want a string to either take a numeric format, with '.' For thousands and decimals use ',' so far I get that statement but not with 9.9 and 99.9 it's wrong not giving Oracle error. I would like to make a sentence where everything works.